# Use Game Engines to develop general purpose mobile apps is it a bad pratice? Scenes vs Activities

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm trying to develop an regular application for Android using Android Studio in the latest version, but I can't even prototype it because everything is incredible slow.

I don't if the fault is my PC Setup (Phenom II 955, 8GB RAM, GTX 1060 - But I'll upgrade the damn old 955 for a brand new i5 7400 as soon enough, waiting the money) or if Android Studio by IntelliJ really sucks. It's not only the ARM emulator, all the interface, the click n drag of UI components freezes all the time. And to be honest Java is not my strongest, I do something or another but nothing too complex. C# or C++ fits fine for me.

So I was/am looking for alternatives. A little time ago I tried Corona SDK (largely used for gaming but there are some general apps cases too). First instance I loved it, the emulator runs so fine and smooth, the libs is easy to understand but the Lua syntax didn't fit good for me, I have no maestry on it (is not hard, I just don't have time to waste, you know)

Maestry I got on Unity3D using C# I could prototype and develop really fast on it. But the question is I don't know if it's a good pratice using the scenes system of game engines instead of activities. I'm not talking about Unity3D, but also pure C++ libs like Oxygine2D, OpenGLES2 for example. Is there impact on performance for regular users who don't have a high end smartphone? Using Game engines can make the code seem dirty and tricky or it's common and fine? Is it discouraged?

Comment: Use Xamarin. IMHO IntelliJ and Eclipse are to worst IDE's out there. They are horribly slow and not user friendly. You can download VS 2017 and write everything within visual studio using Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game engines refresh every frame, while native apps generally react to system events, it would be very tricky (perhaps impossible) to avoid this. They also increase build size, since you have to include all (or most) engine-related libraries. So they do require more system resources than a native app.

That being said, if you're more comfortable with Unity3D and you just want to make a quick prototype, then I don't see why not.

Moreover, keep in mind that game engines give you a lot more flexibility when it comes to animations, visual effects etc. so if you're making a game-like app (like, for example, trivia game) then a proper game engine like Unity3D might be a good choice.

However I'd recommend making a native app, or trying a cross-platform framework (like Xamarin). The sooner you learn this technology, the better!

Comment: I agree with the build size. Another thing to add is licensing. One is free, the other is not.